# Bootstrap modal sending request more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two modal, #wideModal and #smallModal.
Here is the code for the link,

```
<a href='javascript:openModal("wideModal","funcabc","code101")' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View</a>
```

Here is the code of the function openModal(),

```
function openModal(id,f,data,data1,data2){
    $("#"+id).modal('show');
    $( "#"+id ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        myFunctions[f](data);
    });
}
```

Here is the code for the function funcabc(),

```
function funcabc(data){
    $( "#wideModal .modal-body" ).load( "view.php",data, function() {
    });
}
```

Here is the other codes  related to #wideModal,

```
$( "#wideModal" ).on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $(".modal-content").css("display","flex");
    });
$( "#wideModal" ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#wideModal .modal-content').removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

If the user click the link, at first, It will request to the server once. After the user closed the modal, and click again the link, it will request to the server more than once.

I tried this code,

```
$( "#wideModal" ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).off();
    $('#wideModal .modal-content').removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

to remove all the eventhandler. It is not working.

Comment: you have your javascript triggering in the href attribute, so off() will not affect it. you need to assign the click handler in javascript

Comment: or just do, instead of off, this.removeAttribute('href')

Comment: Still not working.